# Atualizar componente Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

Bom dia!

Resumindo, tenho um componente Navbar e nele tem um if que se estiver logado aparece alguns itens e se não estiver, aparecem outros. Ele funciona, o problema é que para ele validar a mudança, estou precisando dar um F5 pra ele chamar o "IF" de novo. Entao, teria algum modo de eu corrigir isso e ser automática essa mudança?
 Obrigado :D

Comment: Ele loga sem atualizar a página?

Comment: Ciclo de vida talvez? Dependendo do seu modelo de usuário(?) você pode checar se houve alteração no `ngOnChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor modo para fazer isto e com rotas e guarda de rotas ai ficaria assim no guarda de rotas vc coloca

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(
    private ahthSevice: AuthService,
    private _router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state:RouterStateSnapshot
  ):Observable<boolean>|boolean{
if(this.ahthSevice.getUsuarioAutenticado()){

  return true;
}

this._router.navigate([''])
return false;

  }
```

e dentro do app-routing voce coloca

```
const ACHEI_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        component: LoginComponent,

    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: MenuLateralComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
```

Dentro do app.module voce tem que declarar como provaider o guarda

```
  providers: [AuthService,AuthGuard],
```

e criar um servico de autenticao

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Usuario } from './../../classes/usuario';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  private usuarioAutenticado: boolean = false;
  fazerLogin(usuario: Usuario) {

    if (usuario.nome === 'login' &&
      usuario.senha === 'senha') {
      this.usuarioAutenticado = true
      this.router.navigate(['home'])
    } else {

      this.usuarioAutenticado = false
              };
  }

  getUsuarioAutenticado(){
    return this.usuarioAutenticado
  }

}
```